# How to limit the number of images I get back from graphql?

Tags: graphql, relay

We are using graphql and relay, and recompose.

I am getting some data from a `Unit`, but I also need some data from its `Project`.(A unit belongs to a project)

And I have figured out how to, get some images i need from the project like so:

```
project {
  images {
    fileKey
    aspectRatio
  }
```

but i get many images.. like 20.. and i just need the first one.. How do i tell relay or graphQl to give me just one?

Thanks, here is my whole fragment:

```
const enhance = compose(
  fragment(graphql`
      fragment DetailsSectionContainer_unit on Unit {
        tourIdArchilogic
        tourIdMatterport
        images {
          fileKey
          aspectRatio
        }
        ...TitleRowContainer_unit
        ...UnitSummaryContainer_unit
        ...ContactFormColumnContainer_unit
        project {
          images {
            fileKey
            aspectRatio
          }
          ...ContactFormColumnContainer_project
        }
        company {
          ...ContactFormColumnContainer_company
        }
        ...TourContainer_unit
      }
      fragment DetailsSectionContainer_rentedUnit on RentedUnit {
        ...UnitSummaryContainer_rentedUnit
      }
      fragment DetailsSectionContainer_vacantUnit on VacantUnit {
        ...UnitSummaryContainer_vacantUnit
      }
  `),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the return type of your images to a connection, then you tell the server how many images you want to fetch like this:

```
project {
   images(first: 1) {
        edges {
          node {
              fileKey
              aspectRatio
          }
       }
   }
}
```

More about connections here ->
[Grahpql connections](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm)